# Scala Spark: Filter rows based on values in a column of Floats

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Why isn't the following code working? I am trying to filter out rows such that they contain values in: `[10.0, 100.0]. Both of the following solutions produce the same result. Do I need to` Cast()` or something?

Solution 1:

```
dff1.select("hrs").filter(col("hrs").geq(lit("10")) && 
                          col("hrs").leq(lit("100")) ).show(10, truncate = false)
```

Solution 2:

```
dff1.select("hrs").filter(col("hrs") >= lit("10") && 
                          col("hrs") <= lit("100") ).show(10, truncate = false)
```

Result:

```
+------------------+
|hrs               |
+------------------+
|239.78444444444443|
|24.459444444444443|
|238.05944444444444|
|45.05138888888889 |
|213.6225          |
|20.04388888888889 |
|201.45333333333335|
|4393.384166666667 |
|260.2611111111111 |
|47.83083333333333 |
+------------------+
```

Comment: "Do I need to Cast()` or something?" What happens if you try?

Comment: @mike I would try if I knew what to Cast to or the syntax to use to do it.

Comment: At the moment it looks like you are trying to compare a floating number with a string. Try change `lit("10")` to `lit(10)` and the same for the value of 100.

Comment: When you do dff1.printSchema you will see which data type the columns hrs actually has.

Comment: Thanks. More generally, Python has a function `dir(object)` that tells you what functions work on it. Does Scala have an equivalent and if so, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

`lit` is not necessary for integers or floats:

```
dff1.select("hrs").filter(col("hrs") >= 10 && col("hrs") <= 100)
```

should also work.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use expressions for the filter. The expression would be the same as you use it in SQL "where" clause (leave the integers/floats as such and wrap the string constants in single quotes).

So your transformation becomes.

```
dff1.select("hrs").filter(" hrs >= 10 and hrs <= 100 ")
```

Comment: I'm curious, why are expressions better to use for the filter? Is it better in the sense of being computationally faster for reason(s) XYZ? I find both methods above to be equally legible.

Comment: @user2205916.. it improves readability and also portable. Same SQL syntax is used and  removes the clutter caused by "(", ")" etc.. easy to debug.. Remember spark has been designed to be SQL compatible, so except few dataframe transformations, you can write the SQL equivalent using expr().

Comment: do you know if SQL syntax is slower than Scala operations/methods?

Comment: no.. both are same.. just the style of writing code..